# Return picture from server through spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my spring controller, I add this two methods, to upload and download a picture from my views:

```
@RequestMapping(value="picture/{theString}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public byte[] getPicture(@PathVariable("theString") String theString) {
    return serv.download_picture(theString);
}

@RequestMapping(value="upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean setPicture(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    return serv.upload_picture(object, file);
}
```

the setPicture (with the equivalent upload_picture in the service class) are already implemented, but I need some ideas about how implement the download_picture, in the way I be able to do something like that:

```
<img src="<c:url value="<<Entity>>/picture/<<id>>"/>">
```

anyone can point a direction to do that?

PS.: If possible, I want use this declaration for my method download_picture in my service class:

```
public byte[] download_picture(String path) {
    return null;
}
```

where path is the id from the entity I want download a picture.

PS.: The pictures are stored in the folder `/src/main/resources` in my spring/maven application. the full URL inside this path is something like `<<entity>>/<<id>>/foto.jpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring having version 3.1 or newer you can specify `produces` in `@RequestMapping` annotation.
Below is Sample Example.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("picture/{theString}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public byte[] testphoto(@PathVariable("theString") String theString) throws IOException 
{
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/images/no_image.jpg"); // 
    //Here you may write above code in service class to read file from path "/src/main/resources" as stream and return it to controller class.

    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

May this help you.

Reference :
[Image Download with Spring MVC](https://gist.github.com/kjunine/7578710).